# Unity2D: Creating a wavy score text animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to animate my score text into a wavy animation each time the player picks up a coin as well as make another wavy text animation but going the opposite way each time the player loses some coins. I already have a code (shown below) to make a certain text do a wavy animation, however to do this I assigned each character of the text to either go up or down to initially make a wavy animation, as shown here:

[image: gif].

**My problem is**: If I were to do this method for the score text, there is no telling how much coins the player will get and so it will make it difficult for me to estimate how much characters I would need for the score text as the possibility of the player adding a new digit to the score is kind of random.

So is there a way for me to create a wavy text animation to my score text? Thank you!

```c#
public GameObject WaveTextObj, text1, text2, text3, text4;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    text1.SetActive (false);
    text2.SetActive (false);
    text3.SetActive (false);
    text4.SetActive (false);
    StartCoroutine (WaveEffect ());
}

IEnumerator WaveEffect() {
    while (true) {
       WaveTextObj.SetActive (true);              
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.3f);
        text1.SetActive (true);             
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.08f);
        text2.SetActive (true);           
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.17f);
        text3.SetActive (true);         
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.19f);
        text4.SetActive (true);        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.4f);
        WaveTextObj.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

**NEW UPDATE**

```c#
 text = "Testing";
 string[] characters = new string[text.Length];
 for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
 {
       characters[i] = text[i].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Rather than turning things on and off, you should break the string into a list of characters, make each character its own object, then animate those objects up and down based on `Mathf.sin(Time.time)`

Comment: @Draco18s is right. You can  break the text into list of characters and the animated them. Then you will not have to estimate the characters or the coins

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Draco18s , however I'm not sure how I would use "Mathf.sin(Time.time)" to animate each object up and down. This is what I have come up with so far, look at my question ^^

Answer (score 1):

## Use Mathf.Sin(Time.time)

```
public GameObject WaveTextObj;
public GameObject textPrefab;

IEnumerator WaveEffect(string text) {
    //clear out the existing text
    while(WaveTextObj.transform.childCount > 0) {
        Destroy(WaveTextObj.transform.GetChild(0));
    }
    //create new text
    float scalar = 0.1f;
    float timeScalar = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
       GameObject o = Instantiate(textPrefab, new Vector3(i * scalar,0,0), Quaternion.Identity, WaveTextObj.transform)
       o.GetComponent<Text>().text = text[i].ToString();
    }
    //animate text
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform child in transform) {
            Vector3 p = child.localPosition;
// By setting each text object's y position to a value controlled by a sine wave,
// they will jiggle up and down. Their index in the string handles each letter being
// at a different point on the wave.
            p.y = Mathf.Sin((Time.time + i * scalar) * timeScalar) * scalar;
            child.localPosition = p;
            i++;
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

Up to you to figure out how you want exit the loop. Several values are arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried out what you suggested but for some reason when I run the code and my game, unity crashes! Do you have any idea what might cause this? Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: I didn't actually run this code, but two things come to mind: either of the two `GameObject` variables aren't initialized or the prefab doesn't have a`Text` component attached. Possible third, it dies trying to clear out the WaveText parent transform hierarchy because I didn't do that correctly. What's the error?

Comment: There is no error that appears in the game's console, the unity just crash and I receive a unity bug reporter message box!

Comment: Weird. Don't know of hand and can't check this myself until next week.